# What is a good way to identify iOS device from User Agent?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-agent, ipod

Do all iOS devices send `iPhone`, `iPad` or `iPod` as part of the User Agent?

Is it a good practice to test for those three strings to identify iOS devices?

Does it work for all browsers including Safari, Firefox, Opera(?), etc?

Using Ruby. I know I can use a gem but don't think it is necessary...

Answer (score 0):

The rendering software for IOS commonly used is AppleWebKit (safari, chrome and firefox). 
It is included in user agent.
Some other browser could differ.

Comment: Unfortunately `AppleWebKit` won't work because OSX sends it as well: `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36`

Comment: What if you use both the Applewebkit filter with the platform field (Macintosh in your example).
It should be, for IOS:
- "iPhone||iPad ...AppleWebKit" using Safari and chrome
- "Mobile||Tablet ... AppleWebKit" using firefox for IOS